# Is there a way to combine values from a form with another form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to coding, and I have a form where I use forward geocoding to look-up the location of a restaurant. When the location is found there is another form where the user can fill in extra information about the restaurant.

I want to combine all of these before I send a POST request to my server.

```
function addNewRestaurant(values) {

    setValues(lat, lon, values);

    dispatch(postNewRestaurant(formValues, token, userId));
  }
```

The problem is, I don't get all of the values in formValues

Comment: It's difficult to comment anything by just looking at this code you provided

Comment: "Is there a way?" Yes.

Comment: so just combine them. you have a form that you binded its values to a state like `formValues1` and another form with state like: `formValues2`. now you can combine the datas like: `{form1: formValues1, form2: formValues2}` or any other format and send it to server. what's the exact problem?

Comment: Please put the code where you are constructing values for `formValues`